# Poisson brackets for a field theory

Tags: field-theory, hamiltonian-formalism, phase-space, classical-field-theory, poisson-brackets

I'm performing a calculation involving Dirac constraints theory, and I need to calculate the Poisson brackets between constraints and the total Hamiltonian. The starting theory is described by a Lagrangian density depending on two fields (say, L(X,Y)) and I realized I'm not familiar with a definition of Poisson brackets for a field theory involving more than a single field. I wasn't able to find a book that generalizes the standard definition for discrete systems (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poisson_bracket) to fields, so my first question is a good book for reference.
Secondly, by thinking by analogy I came up with two different ways to solve my problem:

1. I define a Poisson bracket for every couple of field-momentum:
   \begin{equation}
     \left\{ f,g \right\}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial g}{\partial V}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial V}\frac{\partial g}{\partial X}
   \end{equation}
   for the PB with respect to the field X and the corresponding momentum V, and:
   \begin{equation}
     \left\{ f,g \right\}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial g}{\partial W}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}\frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}
   \end{equation}
   for the PB with respect to the field Y and the corresponding momentum W
2. I define a single PB summing up for all the field-momentum couples (similarly to che standard definition):

\begin{equation}
  \left\{ f,g \right\}= \frac{\partial f}{\partial X}\frac{\partial g}{\partial V}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial V}\frac{\partial g}{\partial X} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial Y}\frac{\partial g}{\partial W}-\frac{\partial f}{\partial W}\frac{\partial g}{\partial Y}
\end{equation}

Can someone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't help you with references, but there are lots of works on classical canonical transformations in classical field theory.

It is standard for one pair of conjugate fields  $X(x)$ and $V(x)$ and a functional of them, $f[X,V]$, to consider
$$
  \left\{ f[X,Y] , g[X,Y]\right \}= \int\!\! dx ~~~\Bigl (
 \frac{\delta  f}{\delta  X(x)}\frac{\delta  g}{\delta V(x)}-
 \frac{\delta  f}{\delta  V(x)}\frac{\delta  g}{\delta X(x)} \Bigr ),
 $$
generalizing the standard multivariable expression to an infinite vector of variables, the fields.

If you have several fields, you may index fields to $X^i(x)$ and $V^i(x)$, and you further multiplex the above expression to discrete vectors whose  components are infinite-dimensional fields,
$$
  \left\{ f[X,Y] , g[X,Y]\right \}=\sum_i \int\!\! dx ~~~\Bigl (
 \frac{\delta  f}{\delta  X^i(x)}\frac{\delta  g}{\delta V^i(x)}-
 \frac{\delta  f}{\delta  V^i(x)}\frac{\delta  g}{\delta X^i(x)} \Bigr ).
 $$

Recall
$$
  \left\{ X^k(z) , V^j(y)\right \}= \delta^{kj} \delta (z-y)~~.
 $$